# Vb.net delete from multiple listviews

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a system that inserts data into two Listviews, when it selects a Line in Listviews1 and clicks the button it DELETE selected line.
But I need that erases to the other Listview, since the data are the same.
To delete in Listviews1 I use this code:

Dim lvi As ListViewItem

```
    For Each lvi In lv1.SelectedItems

        lvi.Remove()
    Next
```

Comment: Are the same items selected in the other listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to run a reverse `for loop` and remove from both listviews based on the index of any selected items found. The reason for this is if you run top-down, you are altering the collection and you won't be able to remove items as that would change indexes. Here's what I would start with.

```
    For x As Integer = Lv1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1 
        If Lv1.Items(x).Selected = True Then
            Lv2.Items(x).Remove()
            Lv1.Items(x).Remove()
        End If
    Next
```

This code assumes Lv1 is the listview with the items selected. What it's doing is starting at the last item in the list and checking to see if it's selected. If it is, it removes that item based on its index from lv2 and also from itself. This repeats on up lv1 until it reaches index 0. It also requires that both lv's have the same data which you stated was in fact the case. What you didn't specify is whether or not the data is also in the same row for each lv. If that is not the case, this will not work. It removes row for row only. In other words if you had lv1 with rows `red, green & blue` and lv2 with rows `blue, red & green` and you hilighted red in lv1 then blue would be removed from lv2 because blue is in the same row as red.